# Why does only the last source sheet's info get posted on the target sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach

I'm trying to post information from multiple source spreadsheets to a target spreadsheet in google sheets. Everything should've worked right as i tested wit Logger.log(), however only the last source spreadsheet's info gets posted on the target spreadsheet. What am I doing wrong?

```
function retrieveData(ssA,ssB) {
/* Gets the source sheets' id values typed manually in a range of cells on active sheet*/
var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetValues(2, 3, 4,1);
  /*Gets the source sheets'names typed manually in a range of cells on active sheet*/
var sourceSpreadsheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetValues(2, 4, 4, 1);
  /* loops through an array containing source sheets' ids*/
ssA.forEach(function(ssA){
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssA)
/*loops through an array containing source sheets' names */
sourceSpreadsheetName.forEach(function(sourceSpreadsheetName){
var ss = sss.getSheetByName(sourceSpreadsheetName)
if(ss != null) {
  /* gets range on each source sheet */
var SRange = ss.getRange(2, 1, 50, 2);
  /*gets A1 notation on each source sheet*/
var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  /*gets cell values on each source sheet */
var SData = SRange.getValues();
  /* target sheet id */
var ssB = '1Dp1dOcwaup184mt1zWU-lcA5Nw-jFguWrr_H2hrtKSg';
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssB);
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Customers need to contact');
  /* sets values retrieved from source sheets on target sheet*/
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData); 
}
})
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Modify your code adding logs as following:

```
function retrieveData(ssA,ssB) {
/* Gets the source sheets' id values typed manually in a range of cells on active sheet*/
var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetValues(2, 3, 4,1);
  /*Gets the source sheets'names typed manually in a range of cells on active sheet*/
var sourceSpreadsheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetValues(2, 4, 4, 1);
  /* loops through an array containing source sheets' ids*/
ssA.forEach(function(ssA){
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssA)
/*loops through an array containing source sheets' names */
sourceSpreadsheetName.forEach(function(sourceSpreadsheetName){
var ss = sss.getSheetByName(sourceSpreadsheetName)
if(ss != null) {
  Logger.log('spreadsheet and sheet: '+sss.getName()+ss.getName());
  /* gets range on each source sheet */
var SRange = ss.getRange(2, 1, 50, 2);
  /*gets A1 notation on each source sheet*/
var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  Logger.log('a1 notation: '+A1Range);
  /*gets cell values on each source sheet */
var SData = SRange.getValues();
  /* target sheet id */
var ssB = '1Dp1dOcwaup184mt1zWU-lcA5Nw-jFguWrr_H2hrtKSg';
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssB);
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Customers need to contact');
  /* sets values retrieved from source sheets on target sheet*/
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData); 
}
})
})
}
```

and you will see that you retrieve from each source sheet the range `A2:B51` and paste it into range `A2:B51` of the target sheet. This means that you overwrite the pasted values in each iteration step.

### **The issue can be resolved by e.g. appending the values from each source sheet to the destination sheet with**

```
var lastRow=ts.getLastRow();
ts.getRange(lastRow,1,50,2).setValues(SData);
```